# Hide first closest parent element using javascript (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to hide a html class when button clicked.

The html structure is like this:

```
<thead>
  <tr class="employee-list">
     <th>
         <button class="show-emp">Show Employee</button>
     </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="emp">
   <tr class="employee-list">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="employee-list-last">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 2</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="emp">
   <tr class="employee-list">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="employee-list-last">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 2</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also I can have more than one .emp class.

I've tried something like code bellow, but still not working (it hide all element with `.emp` class)

```
$('.show-emp').click(function() {
   $(this).closest(".emp").hide();
});
```

The ilustration how it works is like this:
[image]

When `show` button clicked, it will only hide/show the employee list bellow it.

Comment: `$('.show-emp').click(function() {
   $(this).closest(".emp:eq(0)").hide();
});`

Comment: @stillKonfuzed thanks, but it still hide all element with `emp` class

Comment: How about `$firstEmpEL = $(this).parent().parent().find('tbody.emp').eq(0); $($firstEmpEL).hide();`

Comment: I would suggest console logging it until you find the element, then hide it.

Comment: Can you post HTML with more than one `.emp` element?

Comment: "closest" means the closest ancestor of the element (this seems to be a common misunderstanding, I don't know why). There are no ancestors of `.show-emp` with `class="emp"`. So it shouldn't be hiding anything.

Comment: `Hide first closest parent element` . Closest of `button.show-emp` does not have `.emp`

Comment: thanks everyone, I already solved it using answer from @Devsi Odedra

Comment: How is it supposed to know which `.emp` should be hidden?

Comment: ah my mistake, when I tested it using more than 1 `.emp` it's not working correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.closest()` finds the closest parent element that matches the selector, but `.emp` isn't a parent of `.show-emp`.

You want to go up to the `thead`, then find the first sibling after it that matches the selector.

`.nextAll()` will find all the following siblings that match. Use `.first()` to get the first one.

```js
$('.show-emp').click(function() {
  $(this).closest("thead").nextAll(".emp").first().toggle();
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text == 'Show Employee' ? 'Hide Employee' : 'Show Employee';
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr class="employee-list">
      <th>
        <button class="show-emp">Hide Employee</button>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="emp">
    <tr class="employee-list">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="employee-list-last">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="emp">
    <tr class="employee-list">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="employee-list-last">
      <td style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Both answers can't be right when there are multiple `.emp` in the table.

Comment: this is only hide/show the first element inside the table, what I need to do if I want the closest one to the button instead?

Answer (score 1):

First of all correct your markup and jquery properly.

1. check your `<button` tag
2. Jquery code here `('.show-emp')`

You can achieve it many way. one of the below way.

```js
$('.show-emp').click(function() {
   $(this).parents().siblings('.emp').first().hide();
   
   // to hide only first sibling then use //first()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr class="employee-list">
     <th>
         <button class="show-emp"> Btn </button>
     </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="emp">
   <tr class="employee-list">
      <th style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 1</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="employee-list-last">
      <th style="width: 300px" class="text-center">Employee 2</th>
   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry there's a typo in my html & jquery script. Also this is working for me, thanks

Comment: Sorry but when I have multiple `emp` class, it only hide the first element on the table, not the closest one

Comment: in that case you need to use parent of both head and body as per @Barmar 's answer.